# hello at the time of installation magento show error Installation is incomplete. Check the console log for errors before trying again

Tags: magento2

Console Log show error
[ERROR] LogicException: Unknown module in the requested list: 'Magento_BundleSampleData' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:417 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(378): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->readListOfModules(Array, Array, 'enable_modules') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(325): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->createModulesConfig(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(103): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\setup\index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #14 {main}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable this module by going to "Customize Your Store" "Advanced Modules Configurations" and uncheck "Magento_BundleSampleData"

If you would still like to install with this module i would advise you to try clearing all your cache maybe restart apache and mysql and make sure to be in incognito.